# AntiPalindromic Strings

Tags: c

Actually this is one of the challenges from hackerearth. Here is the link to the problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/antipalindromic-strings

I somehow figured a way to find the answer. But the problem my code doesn't get accepted due to timeout. Please help me which part makes my code slower.

This is my code :

```
int anti_palindrome(long int n,long int m,int mod)
{

    int prod;
    prod=m;
    if(n>1)
        prod=prod*(m-1);
    if(n>2)
    {
        n=n-2;
        while(n)
        {
            prod=prod*(m-2);
            n--;
        }
    }
    return prod%mod;
}

int main()
{
    char scanned[1000];
    int input = 0;
    int T=0;
    int T_cur=0;
    long int N,M;
    char str[1000];
    int mod=1000000007;



    while(fgets(scanned,1000,stdin))
    {
        switch(input)
        {
        case 0:  {
            T=atoi(scanned);
            input=1;
        }
            break;
        case 1: {
            T_cur++;
            strcpy(str,scanned);
            sscanf(str,"%d %d",&N,&M);
            //printf("%lf %lf\n",N,M);
            printf("%d\n",anti_palindrome(N,M,mod));
        }
            break;
        }

        if(T_cur==T)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any one run of the program may need to process up to 10<sup>5</sup> `N`, `M` pairs, with `N` and `M` each between 1 and 10<sup>9</sup>.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this algorithm works. Consider N = 4 and M = 4. Let us say, characters in our set are A, B, C and D. Basically you are choosing first character in 4 ways, second character in 3 ways and all the other characters are chosen from rest of the two characters (with possible repeats). So, this shall not subtract the case 'ABCC' or 'ABDD' for example, which clearly contain palindromic substrings of size > 1. Can you please enlighten me why this algorithm works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me which part makes my code slower.

There aren't many parts to consider.  Generally speaking, I/O is much slower than computation, but you haven't any more I/O than is needed, so let's disregard that for the moment.

Consider, then, your `anti_palindrome()` function.  In the general case, it loops `N` times, performing three arithmetic operations and two assignments in each iteration.  That's not expensive on a per-iteration basis, but you may have a billion iterations per test case, and ten thousand test cases, for a total of around 5x10<sup>14</sup> mixed operations.  That number of operations is going to take more than a few seconds.

While I'm at it, I observe that your algorithm is wrong anyway.  You are supposed to report the answer modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7, but long before you get to the end of the computation, you will have overflowed the `prod` variable.  The resulting behavior is undefined.  If prod had an unsigned type then the behavior would be defined, but still wrong.  Switching to `pow()` instead of a loop would improve the performance enormously, but would not solve this problem.  You need something cleverer.

Comment: I understand it . I've tried fast exponentiation with mod 10^9 + 7 but even that failed

Answer (score -1):

As `m-2` is constant, write `m= m-2;` before the loop. Now, what remains is that n times `prod=prod*m;` is executed. This is equivalent to `prod= prod*pow(m,n);` The math library may have an efficient implementation of pow() that will prevent your timing issue.

In C you may have to cast the parameters to double, and the return value to long int.

```
int anti_palindrome(long int n,long int m,int mod)
{
    int prod;
    prod=m;
    if(prod>1)
        prod=prod*(m-1);
    if(prod>2)
    {
        n=n-2;
        m=m-2;
        prod= prod*pow(m,n);
    }
    return prod%mod;
}
```